# Why is HSV used to detect color in image processing and not RGB?

Tags: image, rgb, hsv

I have a question about image processing, to track color we use HSV and not RGB, even though HSV also has 3 components.

**What is the real advantage of using HSV instead of RGB?**

Comment: Tried to rephrase the question.

Comment: This is the same question as: [Why do we use the HSV colour space so often in vision and image processing?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing)

Answer (score 0):

Using of HSV instead of RGB is a great advantage because it separates colour info from the intensity info.
for ex: If you want to do histogram equalization for RGB image you have to separate the intensities info from colour info because while doing Histogram equalization the colour info shouldn't change only the intensities info should change.